# Get Session data in store function

Tags: php, laravel, session, request

Is it right to get Session data in a store function and store them into db?

```
public function store(){    
  ...
  $idgroup = Session::get('invitation_userid')];
  ...
}
```

Or need a store function always a Request Object?

```
public function store(Request $request){    
  ...
  $idgroup = $request('idgroup');
  ...
}
```

In both functions is of course a validation part for the input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches are fine, but you should use them appropriately to your use case, I prefer to use the `Request` data. The main difference is that if u store that inside the `Session` it will be available application wide, while if u send inside `Request` it will be available inside the method only

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on the context of what your controller is actually named, how this data is being used and why you are not using a database session driver in the first place if you want to do this.

You could simply use the database driver for the session:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#introduction

It also depends on what your controller is named if you strictly want to follow restful routes:

https://gist.github.com/alexpchin/09939db6f81d654af06b

To answer the second question you don't always need a `Request` object in your `store` action. Most of the time you won't even see a `Request` object because you are simply creating an entirely new resource.

Answer (score 0):

The Global Session Helper
You may also use the global session PHP function to retrieve and store data in the session. When the session helper is called with a single, string argument, it will return the value of that session key. When the helper is called with an array of key / value pairs, those values will be stored in the session:

`$value = session('key');`